# Exception translator interceptor. Good idea?

Tags: java, oop

just wanted to ask for some opinion:
Do you think it is a good idea to have an interceptor class that intercepts all exceptions and translates them into application-specific exceptions? Basically exception handling (and nothing else) is moved out from a class into another.

Can you please give any pros/cons on this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you add some sample code showing what you are thinking about?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a reasonable idea. Have a look at Spring's `org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionTranslator` for an example. It's particularly good for translating irritating checked exceptions into unchecked ones.

The usual downside is increased complexity - so it depends how many application-specific exceptions you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's a really bad idea. If I use an interface which documents that it throws an IllegalArgumentException for some condition, I expect to get an IllegalArgumentException if this condition is met, and not some application-specific exception.

If it has a bug and it throws a NullPointerException, I prefer getting a NullPointerException identifying the problem directly, rather than having it encloses in some application-specific exception which doesn't tell what and where the problem is.

Now, if your class is not an interceptor in the AOP sense, but a wrapper around another object or API (like spring-jdbc is a wrapper around JDBC for example) and if it only transforms checked exceptions into application-specific exceptions in a meaningful way, I wouldn't see any problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that it can be used to reduce complexity in some cases.  I have an app with an embedded database; I could get missing records, sql exceptions, all kinds of things, none of which I want to report to my user.  Some UI class has a method that calls another method that calls, etc., and somewhere some code runs into one of these and starts passing it back up.  At the appropriate level, which is specific to an application design, I trap that, probably log it, and wrap it in an application-specific exception which job it is to produce a message that leads my user to do the correct thing with it, besides notifying him that something is wrong.  The app-specific exception is tailored to the user that's going to see the resulting message, and can be generated in response to a bunch of "lower-level" exceptions that I need to trap but don't want to report.